# Getting empty list while parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing jeevansathi.com and want to select `<ul>` with id `#profileInfo2` but after using BeautifulSoup I am getting empty list Below is the code and the output

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.jeevansathi.com/search/quick/169903999/1')
try:    
  res.raise_for_status()
  nazia=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
  print type(nazia)
  elems=nazia.select("#profileInfo2")
  print type(elems)
  print len(elems)
except Exception as exc:
  print("There was a problem: %s" % (exc))
```

output is

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
<type 'list'>
0
```

Comment: Sure the content you're after isn't generated by JavaScript? Can you find any of the selectors in the raw response text?

Comment: For javascript sites some other primary method then bs4

Comment: yes I am sure the content isn't generated by javascript because without any event handler [link]http://www.jeevansathi.com/search/quick/169903999/1 just view the source code you will get `<ul id="profileInfo2">`

Comment: @Rachid, right click and choose view source then you won't see `#profileInfo2`, you will see `id="profileInfo{profileNoId}"`

Comment: @padraic you are right, I understood the issue, Now can anyone guide how to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is dynamically loaded, you can see the template it in what requests returns or if you look at the view source in your browser:

```
<div class="pt10 fontlig colr4 clearfix ulinline">
<ul id="profileInfo{profileNoId}" class="fl f14 wid83p descplist">
<li class="textTru">{age},  {height}</li>
<li class="textTru">{edu_level_new}</li>
<li class="textTru">{location}</li>
<li class="textTru">{occupation}</li>
<li class="textTru">{religion}, {caste}</li>
<li class="textTru">{income}</li>
<li class="textTru">{mtongue}</li>
<li class="textTru">{mstatus}</li>
</ul>
```

You can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to get the source as you see it in your browser combining it with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) for headless browsing:

```
from selenium import webdriver

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

dr.get('http://www.jeevansathi.com/search/quick/169903999/1')
ul = dr.find_element_by_id("profileInfo2")
print()
```

That would give you the ul with the id *profileInfo2*, if you wanted each li inside you can also use a css selector:

```
lis = dr.find_elements_by_css_selector("#profileInfo2  li")
```

And to pull the text from each:

```
 [li.text for li in lis])
```

You probably want all the uls which you can get with:

```
all_uls = dr.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul[id^=profileInfo]")
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic it is really helpful

Answer (score -1):

The content #profileInfo2 is not present in the page if you disable javascript in your browser, so it will not show up in python either without javascript.

You can easily verify this by accessing the site with Firefox and an active NoScript Addon, and searching for #profileInfo2 in the html source code.